# add and remove class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class='fixed_button homes hidden'>
    <a class='btn btn-primary homes'>Continue &rarr;</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".homes").on('click', function(){
    $("choose_style").addClass('hidden');
    $("choose_town").removeClass('hidden'); 
});
```

I need the .choose_town div to show and the .choose_style div to hide when I click the button. 
Nothing happens when the button gets clicked though.

Comment: You forgot to add `.` before the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the `.`

```
$(".choose_style").addClass('hidden');
$(".choose_town").removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: I'm really new to this javascript thing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the '**.**'  (for a class) or '#' (for an Id)

Check it [`$(".class")`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) or it [`$("#id")`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$(".choose_style").addClass('hidden');
$(".choose_town").removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your $("choose_style") and $("choose_town") are missing . or #

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple by jQuery and Love this method:

```
$("id").addClass('class');
$("id").removeClass('class');
```

just place and understand these classes functionality what you want to do.